# SpringBoot connecion timeout

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I configured like this:

```
server:
  port: 8080
  servlet:
    context-path: /user
  tomcat:
    connection-timeout: 3s
    threads:
      max: 1 
      min-spare: 1 
    accept-count: 1
    max-connections: 1
```

But when I tried with Jmeter,
connections are not dropped immediately unitl waiting for 50 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

try this maybe:

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=60s
```

In your case, Tomcat will not allow to set the timeout any less than 60 seconds : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7383

Comment: Thanks,but it's not the problem I met.

Comment: Not sure if this is the case but check this maybe:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/21914#issuecomment-645170092

Comment: My problem is not to timeout from server side,I mean when the num of connections is full, other connections can be rejected immediately.

Comment: In that case we are not talking about timeout; we are talking about max-connections ... check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60502791/6150881